# is it possible query data that are not equal to the specified condition?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Am fetching list of users for my listview (android) i used firebaselistadapter to backing up my listview , I wanna show  users data except mine .
Like an sql query Select something from usertable where id!=userid;

i wanna fetch all other users data,

Comment: Nope. Currently there is no way to *exclude* certain values in a query, only to *include* it.

Comment: Looks like an answer, Frank!

Comment: Yeah yeah... I thought this had been covered before, so was hoping *someone* would help me out and look up the dupe for me. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Firebase currently only offers a way to *include* nodes based on the presence of a certain value. You **cannot** exclude nodes based on the presence of a value.

Update (20160828): I wrote a related answer today that shows [how to detect the absence of a property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39195551).

Comment: @Frank is there any workaround to do this? If not, filtering results once loaded at the client would be a good idea?

Comment: if there's nothing to return, does the callback still get fired?

Comment: @Frank is it possible to do logical or / and conditions inside equalTo condition?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, using angularfire and geofire I am searching for business prospects within a radius and trying to create a lead only for new prospects, that means to exclude any existing account already with an existing relation. To do so I need to open a firebaseObject for each key returned by geofire and after $loaded() , check for _.isNull(loadedFirebaseObject.$value). The  lodash function _.isNull() returns null if the firebaseObject path does not exists (a prospect) or undefined if it exists (not a prospect but an existing account).

Is there a better way of doing this?