# Filter ng-repeat with Firebase Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, geofire

I have a set of events that I repeat, and they can already be filtered by a search box.

```
<div class="well well-sm" ng-repeat="allEvent in allEvents | filter:searchText | orderBy:sortOrder" ng-if="allEvent.event.name">
   <h3 id="cabynTitles">{{allEvent.event.name}}</h3>
   <h3 id="cabynMemNum">{{allEvent.event.time}} </h3>
   <button class="btn" ng-click="joinEvnt(allEvent.event.$id)">Join</button>
</div>
```

However, I'm stuck trying *not* show events the user is already going to.  These events are stored in firebase.

```
.filter('myEvents', function () {
return function (items) {
    var filtered = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    var ref = new Firebase(furl + "/users/" + auth.uid + "/events/");
      if (ref.child.equalTo(allEvent.event.$id) !== allEvent.event.$id) {
        filtered.push(item);
           } }
      return filtered;
   } }])
```

I think it's supposed to look something like this, but I can't pass the 'allEvent.event.$id' to the filter (which is the firebase key for the event).  Any help would be awesome, thanks!

**Edit**

Current data looks like-

myEvents:

```
"events": {
      "-KAw4iDuN2KdN-5pfQs0": true,  //Instead of true, I can also make this the uid
      "-KAw7Nn04WEoTDbatPn4": true
}
```

All Events: I'm using geofire, so I get each event back during the geoQuery function, and with that I get all the event details.

```
"-KAw4iDuN2KdN-5pfQs0": {
        "name": "Event Name"
        "description": "Blah blah"
         ...
}
```

I realize now the data has to be filtered before I ng-repeat it, and since I'm using geoFire, I'm trying to filter it with something like this during geoQuery:

```
if (myEvents.indexOf(key) == -1) {
    //push evenDetails to array to show in scope
};
```

Where key is the uid of an event, and myEvents is the firebaseArray of the myEvents data from above.  But I'm guessing indexOf doesn't work on firebaseArrays? Because this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting two problems here:

1. [Firebase can only query based on the presence of a value, not on the absence of a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582223/is-it-possible-query-data-that-are-not-equal-to-the-specified-condition)
2. [Firebase can only query for a single value, not for multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560088/firebase-equivalent-to-sql-where-in)

So your solution will be to:

1. load the complete list of events
2. load the list of events the user is going to
3. loop over #1 and exclude any event that's also in #2
4. bind the result list to the `$scope`

**Update** This snippet shows how to accomplish step 3 with the JSON structures you describe.

```js
var myEvents = {
      "-KAw4iDuN2KdN-5pfQs0": true,
      "-KAw7Nn04WEoTDbatPn4": true
};
var allEvents = {
  "-KAw4iDuN2KdN-5pfQs0": {
        "name": "Event Name",
        "description": "Blah blah"
  },
  "-KAw7Nn04WEoTDbatPn4": {
        "name": "Event Name 2",
        "description": "Blah blah"
  },
  "-KAw7Nn04WEoTDbatl9": {
        "name": "Event Name 3",
        "description": "Blah blah"
  }
};
var filteredEvents = [];

Object.keys(allEvents).forEach(function(eventKey) {
  if (Object.keys(myEvents).indexOf(eventKey) == -1) {
    filteredEvents.push(allEvents[eventKey]);
  }
});

document.getElementById('log').innerText = JSON.stringify(filteredEvents);
```

```html
<pre id='log'></pre>
```

Note that there are many other ways to accomplish the same. For example: a Firebase Snapshot, already has a `forEach()` method that loops over its children. And you can get the key of the current child Snapshot with `child.getKey()`.

Comment: Sounds good.  Loading them is no problem, I have allEvents and myEvents, but how do I do step #3?  I've been trying stuff like myEvents.indexOf("Key of a single allEvent"), but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That depends on what you store about the events, both in the global list and in the user's list. It would help if you add a representative snippet of the JSON data (text please, no screenshots) to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help Frank, I added the data.  I'm using geoFire, so Ideally I'm trying to determine if the event matches a myEvent during the geoQuery function.

Comment: Given my recipe above, you should be able to get closer than what you have in your question now. Steps 1 and 2 are yours, then in step 3 you compare the keys. If that's a problem, update your question with the snippet you have.

Comment: Hey Frank, I just updated it right as you were commenting on the snippet I'm using.  Sorry I can't crack this...

Comment: Frank, I finally got it working!  Thanks for all the help.  Your solution didn't quite work because I was dealing with geoFire, so it wasn't pushing the allEvents array, but just a single event at a time.  So I ended up using a snapshot.foreach call to make it happen.  Thanks again for all the help!