# NotQualTo in Firebase Rest call

Tags: rest, firebase, filtering, firebase-realtime-database

In firebase, when we want to filter data we have 3 parameter to query data.

`startAt` - For Start Point [can be used in conjunction with `endAt`]

`endAt`   - For end point [can be used in conjunction with `startAt`]

`equalTo` - For specifying equal to [Used alone]

**Example1**:
to retrieve all dinosaurs with a height greater than 3

```
curl 'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy="height"&startAt=3
```

**Example2** : The following example retrieves all dinosaurs with a name starting with the letter a through m

```
curl 'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy="$key"&startAt="a"&endAt="m"
```

> Question -

Is there any way where I can filter using `notEqualTo`? or similar functionality.

```
curl 'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy="type"&notQualTo="small"
```

So that I can retrieve type `big` and `medium` dinos.

*I am using firebase using REST APIs only.* Another [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582223) is posted which is related to using Firebase in Android

Comment: There is currently no way to filter for the absence of a value or inequality. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582223/is-it-possible-query-data-that-are-not-equal-to-the-specified-condition

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, This Question is about REST and the question you mentioned is Android. Hence not a duplicate. I am also open to suggestion on how this can be achieved if direct functionality is not available.

Comment: The functionality is exactly the same across REST, Android, iOS and JavaScript. The answer I could post here would thus also be exactly the same, which makes it a duplicate.