# Firebase querying - issue with indexing unique ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database structure looks like this (simplified):

```
{
  "articles": {
    "-uniqueId1": {
      "title": "Article 1",
      "category": "news"
    },
    "-uniqueId2": {
      "title": "Article 2",
      "category": "other"
    },
    "-uniqueId3": {
      "title": "Article 3",
      "category": "news"
    },
    "-uniqueId4": {
      "title": "Article 4",
      "category": "news"
    }
  },
  "articlesByCategory": {
    "news": {
      "-uniqueId1": true,
      "-uniqueId3": true,
      "-uniqueId4": true
    },
    "other": {
      "-uniqueId2": true
    }
  }
}
```

The query needs to fetch articles where a specific article's category isn't within. Does that make sense? Say, if `uniqueId2` is of category "other", the query would only fetch articles within "news" and all other existing categories. But since the list may contain, say millions of articles, I have to be as specific as possible and not fetch articles that doesn't match this exact criteria. Therefor, a query like below would be ideal:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref("articlesByCategory");
ref.orderByChild("-uniqueId2").equalTo(null).once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

Here I am searching for categories where a specific property is absent (where a property equals to `null`). This is explained here: [Firebase: Query to exclude data based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195191/firebase-query-to-exclude-data-based-on-a-condition/39195551#39195551)

However, doing a query like this requires me to index every article's unique id on "/articlesByCategory" in the security rules. But it would be unrealistic and non-optimal to dynamically add new article ids inside the ".indexOn" array as that would end up with millions of unique (auto-generated) ids:

```
{
  "articles": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  },
  "articlesByCategory": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    ".indexOn": ["-uniqueId1", "-uniqueId2", "-uniqueId3", "-uniqueId4"...] // List would be endless!
  }
}
```

So how is this achievable? Why am I seeing these sorts of structures (inverted indexing) as ideal solutions everywhere on StackOverflow, but no one seems to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase only can query order statements on nodes with auto-generated ids, and when you've defined your own keys, firebase is unable to perform any sorting/ordering

The ideal way to generate keys is

```
firebase.getInstance().getReference("articles").push(myArticle);
```

this will result in a slightly different database structure like

```
{
"12dakj137_9": { // this is a auto-generated id
"article1": {
  "title": "Article 1",
  "category": "news"
},
"12asjh_123": {
  "title": "Article 2",
  "category": "other"
},...
}
```

Now firebase is able to order/sort and the way you do this is by

```
firebase.getInstance().child("articles").orderByChild("category").equalTo("other");
```

Comment: "article1", "article" etc are unique ids. I have changed them in the first post to "-uniqueId1" etc for better understanding. Anyhow, the way you do the query will fetch articles within category "other". That's not what I'm trying to do. I want to fetch articles that _doesn't_ belong to "other", in which I have to query by an inverted index inside "articlesByCategory", looking for categories that doesn't contain the article by id "-uniqueId2" (because that one has category "other").