# Firebase Android - how to query not equals

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code but I don't what method to use something like `.notEqualsto(uid)`

```
public class CustomAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserVO, ContactViewHolder> {

    public CustomAdapter(DatabaseReference reference, String uid){
        super(UserVO.class,
                R.layout.item_contact,
                ContactViewHolder.class,
                reference.child(FIREBASE_USER_GLOBAL_LIST).orderByChild("email"));
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem that you are actually facing with. please elborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Firebase doesn't provide a method to exclude values in a query, only include (using `equalTo()`). It is possible to [detect the absence of a property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39195551) though.

Comment: According to this blog there is a solution for not equal queries => https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/09/cloud-firestore-not-equal-queries.html