# Firebase filter messages

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I need to list all messages where playerExcluded != firebase.auth().currentUser.uid for each user.

```
roomId
  |__ messageId
         |__ author: string;
         |__ message: string;
         |__ playerExcluded: string;
```

I'm doing that for now with a Cloud Function but I don't think this is a good practice since messages need to be update when there is a new message (=often): this is very costly (a lot of calls to cloud function).

Is there a good way to do that ?

PS/Irrelevant: Is it possible to restrict database query on only one type of query ? Sample example:

```
passwords
    |__ roomId: passwordValue
```

I need to check if the password inputted by the user is right. No problem doing the query doing that. But given that firebase rules with write/read is true OR false, I guess answer is no, can some one confirm it ?

Comment: Firebase does not support `<>` queries. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195191/firebase-query-to-exclude-data-based-on-a-condition/39195551#39195551

Comment: For your second question (please limit yourself to one question per post in the future), you might want to have a look at the section on [query based rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules) in the Firebase documentation. With those you're essentially validating that the query used, is allowed according to your use-case.

Comment: I already saw your first link and knew about this alternative but I found that not really clean to structure my db like that. Is there any update planned to let user query with <> ? Your second link will be usefull. Thank you for your answers Frank !