# Is it possible to query a firebase node by null or undefined?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a project where I use Firebase's real time database. The project has a lot of records so I have been using orderByChild on my queries, so I only get the records I'm interested in and not all records in the node, like so:

```
return this.angularFireDataBase.database.ref().child('users/').orderByChild('is_supervisor').equalTo('si');
```

But now I need to get records whose is_supervisor property is null or doesn't even exist. Is this possible? And how?

Comment: Try `.orderByChild('is_supervisor').startAt('')`, that should get all of the values. Oh wait... you want nodes without (a value for) this property. It looks like this should be possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195191/firebase-query-to-exclude-data-based-on-a-condition/39195551#39195551

Comment: What's wrong with `return this.angularFireDataBase.database.ref().child('users/').orderByChild('is_supervisor').equalTo(null);`?