# firebase - filter on not equal to

Tags: javascript, firebase, filter, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database from which I would like to retrieve all items **except**  the items having a specific value. A function like `notEqualTo()`, so to say.

```
firebase.database()
  .ref().child('/snippets/')
  .orderByChild('description')
  .notEqualTo('dontDisplay')
  .on('value',function(snap) {
    // Working with the right snapshot
  }
```

This obviously does not work since `notEqualTo` is not a function. I also tried passing a function to `equalTo` but this doesn't work either:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref().child('/snippets/')
  .orderByChild('description')
  .equalTo(function (descr) { descr !== 'dontDisplay'; })
  .on('value',function(snap) {
    // Working with the right snapshot
  }
```

What's the right way to filter on items not having the description 'dontDisplay'?

Comment: Unfortunately you can not make this kind of exclusions using Firebase. You have to filter the fetched data. See my answer here to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45321719/7462753

Comment: The Firebase database cannot filter on inequality. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195191/firebase-query-to-exclude-data-based-on-a-condition/39195551#39195551