# How not to show user that is online in recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to create a messaging app.The users who have registered on to my app are showed in users tab but along with those users the user who is currently logged into my app also sees himself in users tab .I don't want user to see himself in users tab.

[image: Users Tab]

My code

> UserAdapter.java

```
    public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<User> mUsers;
    private boolean ischat;

    public UserAdapter(Context mContext, List<User> mUsers,boolean ischat) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mUsers = mUsers;
        this.ischat=ischat;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_item,parent,false);

        return new UserAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final User user=mUsers.get(position);
        holder.username.setText(user.getFirst());

        if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
            holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        } else {
            Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImageURL()).into(holder.profile_image);
        }

        if (ischat){
            if (user.getStatus().equals("online")){
                holder.img_on.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.img_off.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.img_on.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.img_off.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            holder.img_on.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.img_off.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(mContext, MessageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("UserName",user.getFirst());
                intent.putExtra("userid", user.getId());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUsers.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView username;
        public ImageView profile_image;
        private ImageView img_on;
        private ImageView img_off;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            username=itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            profile_image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            img_on = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_on);
            img_off = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_off);
        }
    }
}
```

> UsersFragment.java

```
    public class UsersFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private UserAdapter mUserAdapter;
    private List<User> mUsers;
    String TAG = "MyTag";

    public UsersFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        readUser();


        return view;
    }

    private void readUser() {

        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsers.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user=snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    mUsers.add(user);


                }
                mUserAdapter=new UserAdapter(getContext(),mUsers,false);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);
                mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: how do you indentify which one is current user from users list? I guess you use "MyTag" right?

Comment: There is already an answer this question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43013939/8956604)

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir See When a new user register on my app it is shown in Users Tab to other users who are previously registered on my. But along with this the user who is logged in with that device also sees himself in Users Tab. For example in above the user named Arjun has logged in to the app from that device and another user Shivam has logged in from another device. In this case i don't want user arjun to see himself in Users Tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make condition to check if whether current login user is not not equals to the key node then it will add users in array

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsers.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if(!FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(snapshot.getId())){
                        User user=snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        mUsers.add(user);
                    }
                }
                mUserAdapter=new UserAdapter(getContext(),mUsers,false);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);
                mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: if (!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                        mUsers.add(user);
                    } It Worked