# How to get children with a value not equal to 0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Consider the following JSON format in Firebase database -

```
"root":
{
    "question":
    {
        "1":
        {
            "category":"A",
            "replies":0
        },
        "2":
        {
            "category":"B",
            "replies":1
        },
        "3":
        {
            "category":"B",
            "replies":0
        },
        "4":
        {
            "category":"C",
            "replies":2
        }
    }
}
```

For getting all questions with replies = 0, I do,

```
Query query = rootReference.child("question").orderByChild("replies").equalTo(0);
```

which works perfectly.

But what should I do if I want those questions with replies not equal to 0 ?

Comment: Try using the != syntax instead of .equalTo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the documentation, I see no `notEqualTo()` method or any other way to "negate" a query. However, since you're already calling `.orderByChild("replies")`, you could perhaps use this:

```
Query query = rootReference.child("question").orderByChild("replies").startAt(1);
```

Comment: that I guess will leave others which are !=0&&!=1

Comment: @vikaskumar documentation for `startAt()` says "return child nodes with a value greater than or equal to the given value", so the only problem arises if negative values are possible in OP's data set.

Comment: then I guess this should be the right way to do it. as replies cannot be negative in ideal conditions.

Comment: Great answer Ben!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase currently supports only positive operations, not the negation. 
so you may want to retrieve all the data and then filter it locally.

Here is full [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582223/is-it-possible-query-data-that-are-not-equal-to-the-specified-condition)

Answer (score 0):

Actually Firebase doesn't provide any method to exclude some results like you are seeking here.

However, you can modify your JSON like this & then use following query:

```
// add a different key for all replies = 0, & another different key for non-zero replies
"root":
{
    "question":
    {
        "1":
        {
            "category":"A",
            "replies":0,
            "key2":"someOtherKey"
        },
        "2":
        {
            "category":"B",
            "replies":1,
            "key1":true
        },
        "3":
        {
            "category":"B",
            "replies":0,
            "key2":"someOtherKey"
        },
        "4":
        {
            "category":"C",
            "replies":2,
            "key1":true
        }
    }
}

// now you can use this query to get all non-zero-replies results
// it will give you child 2, 4
Query query = rootReference.child("question").orderByChild("key1").equalTo(true);

// to get all zero-replies childs, use this
Query query = rootReference.child("question").orderByChild("key1").equalTo(null);
```